# Printing elements of a stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char ch;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *first,*top1,*newptr;

void push_back(char data) { //Pushes data into the stack
    if (first == NULL) {
        first = new node();
        first->next = NULL;
        first->ch = data;
    }

    else {
        first = new node();
        top1->next = first;
        top1->ch = data;
        first = top1;
    }
}

void display() {
    top1 = first;

    if (top1 == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty");
        return;
    }

    while (top1 != NULL){
        printf("%c ", top1->ch);
        top1 = top1->next;
    }
}


main() {
    first = NULL;
    char EXP[100];

    scanf("%s",&EXP);
    system("cls");
    int len = strlen(EXP);

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        push_back(EXP[i]);

    display();

    system("pause");
}
```

My program is supposed to get a string a user, and then each character will be placed in a stack, and i'd print the string back. When I run my code, it was only able to display the first character. Am I missing something?

Comment: This code isn't C. You have `new` in it. And yet somehow your compiler manages not to reject `main()` without a return value. By the way, `scanf("%s",&EXP);` is undefined behavior, because they're incompatible types.

Comment: but it was supposed to get a string from the user, what incompatible about that?

Comment: Just remove the ampersand.

Comment: congrats on your first memory leak, may it be the last one!

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push_back() the second time, you immediately overwrite `first`

```
else {
    first = new node();    //oops
    top1->next = first;
    top1->ch = data;
    first = top1;
```

losing the data it pointed to previously.

Comment: okay i already removed it, but now there's a program error :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `top1` is uninitialized and therefore your program exhibits undefined behavior. You most likely made a typo where `first` should be `top1`:

```
void push_back(char data) { //Pushes data into the stack
    // ...
    else {
        top1 = new node();
        top1->next = first;
        top1->ch = data;
        first = top1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your push_back function as well as display function.
You must build a strong base in pointers and memory allocation before jumping to stacks and linkedlists. I recommend this article : http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf
First of all, as remyabel mentioned, top1 should be your new node and not first. first is just a pointer to the top of your stack. I hope you have taken care of that. Coming to your display function, you are iterating from your topmost element,i.e,first which doesn't make sense since it points to null and a stack builds from bottom to top,not vice versa. 
You have to maintain a pointer to the bottom of the stack. Here is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char ch;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *first,*top1,*newptr,*stackbottom;

void push_back(char data) { //Pushes data into the stack
    if (first == NULL) {
        first = new node();
        first->next = NULL;
        first->ch = data;
        stackbottom=first;
    }

    else {
        top1 = new node();
        top1->ch = data;    
        first->next = top1;
        first=top1; 
    }
}

void display(){
    //top1 = first;
    struct node *curr;
    curr=stackbottom;
    if (stackbottom == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty");
        return;
    }

    while (curr != NULL){
        printf("%c ", curr->ch);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}


main() {
    first = NULL;
    char EXP[100];

    scanf("%s",EXP);

    //system("cls");
    int len = strlen(EXP);

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        push_back(EXP[i]);
    //printf("%c",stackbottom->ch);
        //push_back(EXP[1]);

    display();

    //system("pause");
}
```